# what is the difference between db_datareader and db_denydatawriter?

Tags: sql-server, security, role

I am trying to assign a SQL Server database role to a user who just needs to be **able to see data** across all tables.
I was wondering what is the difference between `db_datareader` and `db_denydatawriter`?
From the documentation I don't seem to realize any difference.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to assign a SQL Server database role to a user who just
>   needs to be able to see data across all tables.

You should only make him a member of `db_datareader`.

By default, any newly created `user` has **no permissions at all** (unless you grant something to `public` or the corresponding `login` has some permissions at the `server level`: for example, `view any definition` at the server level implies `view definition` at `database level` once the `login` is mapped to a database).

Comment: This also includes system tables

Answer (score 1):

I think a real-world example of when you would use the `db_denydatawriter` role will help.

One of my clients has a third-party vendor assisting with a long-term (2-year), fixed scope project.  The vendor will be working on the client's domain during the project. For file sharing purposes, the vendor's AD users accounts were made part of an existing AD security group.  We use that same AD security group to grant database access in SQL Server.

We don't want the vendor to be able to make any changes to the database, but we do want them to have the same read access as the other members of the AD security group.

We easily accomplished this by adding the individual vendor AD user accounts to the `db_denydatawriter` role.

---

A good rule of thumb is if you're not sure which role you need, you probably need `db_datareader`.  The use cases for `db_denydatawriter` are far more specialized.